# Is there a name for this type of jagged array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm working with a jagged array representing a hexagon:

```
    x x x
   x x x x
  x x x x x
   x x x x
    x x x
```

or:

```
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxx
xxx
```

I was wondering if this has a name that would help for looking up relevant algorithms etc.

Comment: I can't name it, but I can suggest you a wonderful piece of text on hexagonal grids: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: @werediver This looks very useful, thanks!

Comment: Non-rectangular multidimensional arrays in general are usually called "irregular arrays".